# How to fix this pysqlite2 AttributeError: X instance has no attribute 'con'?

Tags: python, sqlite, pysqlite

When I run the entire code below, this line:

```
res=self.con.execute(
```

From this function (where getfeatures returns a dictionary):

```
def fcount(self,f,cat):
    res=self.con.execute(
      'select count from fc where feature="%s" and category="%s"'
      %(f,cat)).fetchone()
    if res==None: return 0
    else: return float(res[0])
```

Produces this error:

```
AttributeError: naivebayes instance has no attribute 'con'
```

I've installed pysqlite2 and when I run a pysqlite2 test I get OK.

I also tried use the built in sqlite3 instead of pysqlite2 (doing a `import sqlite3` statement and replacing `self.con=sqlite.connect(dbfile)` by `self.con=sqlite3.connect(":memory:")`, but it didn't work either.

How to fix this error?

Thanks for any help.

Here the entire code:

```
from pysqlite2 import dbapi2 as sqlite

import re
import math

def getfeatures(doc):
  splitter=re.compile('\\W*')
  # Split the words by non-alpha characters
  words=[s.lower() for s in splitter.split(doc)
          if len(s)>2 and len(s)<20]
  # Return the unique set of words only
#  return dict([(w,1) for w in words]).iteritems()
  return dict([(w,1) for w in words])

class classifier:
  def __init__(self,getfeatures,filename=None):
    # Counts of feature/category combinations
    self.fc={}
    # Counts of documents in each category
    self.cc={}
    self.getfeatures=getfeatures

  def setdb(self,dbfile):
    self.con=sqlite.connect(dbfile)
    self.con.execute('create table if not exists fc(feature,category,count)')
    self.con.execute('create table if not exists cc(category,count)')


  def incf(self,f,cat):
    count=self.fcount(f,cat)
    if count==0:
      self.con.execute("insert into fc values ('%s','%s',1)"
                       % (f,cat))
    else:
      self.con.execute(
        "update fc set count=%d where feature='%s' and category='%s'"
        % (count+1,f,cat))

  def fcount(self,f,cat):
    res=self.con.execute(
      'select count from fc where feature="%s" and category="%s"'
      %(f,cat)).fetchone()
    if res==None: return 0
    else: return float(res[0])

  def incc(self,cat):
    count=self.catcount(cat)
    if count==0:
      self.con.execute("insert into cc values ('%s',1)" % (cat))
    else:
      self.con.execute("update cc set count=%d where category='%s'"
                       % (count+1,cat))

  def catcount(self,cat):
    res=self.con.execute('select count from cc where category="%s"'
                         %(cat)).fetchone()
    if res==None: return 0
    else: return float(res[0])

  def categories(self):
    cur=self.con.execute('select category from cc');
    return [d[0] for d in cur]

  def totalcount(self):
    res=self.con.execute('select sum(count) from cc').fetchone();
    if res==None: return 0
    return res[0]


  def train(self,item,cat):
    features=self.getfeatures(item)
    # Increment the count for every feature with this category
    for f in features.keys():
##    for f in features:
      self.incf(f,cat)
    # Increment the count for this category
    self.incc(cat)
    self.con.commit()

  def fprob(self,f,cat):
    if self.catcount(cat)==0: return 0

    # The total number of times this feature appeared in this
    # category divided by the total number of items in this category
    return self.fcount(f,cat)/self.catcount(cat)

  def weightedprob(self,f,cat,prf,weight=1.0,ap=0.5):
    # Calculate current probability
    basicprob=prf(f,cat)

    # Count the number of times this feature has appeared in
    # all categories
    totals=sum([self.fcount(f,c) for c in self.categories()])

    # Calculate the weighted average
    bp=((weight*ap)+(totals*basicprob))/(weight+totals)
    return bp




class naivebayes(classifier):

  def __init__(self,getfeatures):
    classifier.__init__(self,getfeatures)
    self.thresholds={}

  def docprob(self,item,cat):
    features=self.getfeatures(item)

    # Multiply the probabilities of all the features together
    p=1
    for f in features: p*=self.weightedprob(f,cat,self.fprob)
    return p

  def prob(self,item,cat):
    catprob=self.catcount(cat)/self.totalcount()
    docprob=self.docprob(item,cat)
    return docprob*catprob

  def setthreshold(self,cat,t):
    self.thresholds[cat]=t

  def getthreshold(self,cat):
    if cat not in self.thresholds: return 1.0
    return self.thresholds[cat]

  def classify(self,item,default=None):
    probs={}
    # Find the category with the highest probability
    max=0.0
    for cat in self.categories():
      probs[cat]=self.prob(item,cat)
      if probs[cat]>max:
        max=probs[cat]
        best=cat

    # Make sure the probability exceeds threshold*next best
    for cat in probs:
      if cat==best: continue
      if probs[cat]*self.getthreshold(best)>probs[best]: return default
    return best


def sampletrain(cl):
  cl.train('Nobody owns the water.','good')
  cl.train('the quick rabbit jumps fences','good')
  cl.train('buy pharmaceuticals now','bad')
  cl.train('make quick money at the online casino','bad')
  cl.train('the quick brown fox jumps','good')


nb = naivebayes(getfeatures)

sampletrain(nb)

#print ('\nbuy is classified as %s'%nb.classify('buy'))
#print ('\nquick is classified as %s'%nb.classify('quick'))

##print getfeatures('Nobody owns the water.')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're code is a mess. Read http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/ first of all. Inherit new classes from object, call parent method using `super()` function instead of direct call, and yes - put `self.set_db()` call in `__init__` method before using con attribute. `AttributeError: naivebayes instance has no attribute 'con'` raises when there is no such attribute, it's not related with db at all.

Comment: Thanks, Victor, but this code is from the (excellent) book "Programming Collective Intelligence". I just copied it from https://raw.github.com/cataska/programming-collective-intelligence-code/master/chapter6/docclass.py and cut part of the code (the fisherclassifier, because I'm using only the naivebayes classifier).  Anyway, thanks!

Comment: Since __init__() in naivebayes was redefined to explicitly call the super class (classifier) to extend its behavior, this way:

    class naivebayes(classifier):

      def __init__(self,getfeatures):
        classifier.__init__(self,getfeatures)

I can't understand what is the problem with the inheritance. How exactly fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Your code sets the connection in `setdb`, but never calls that method. Perhaps you might call it from the `__init__` method.

Answer (score 0):

On page 133 under the section called "Persisting the Trained Classifiers", it says: "After you initialize a classifier, you need to call the setdb method with the name of the database file." That should take care of your problem.

Example:
    cl = docclass.fisherclassifier(docclass.getwords)
    cl.setdb('test1.db')